# Swift: Change the image tint color of tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, tintcolor

I have created the tabBarController programmatically and I want to change color of tint color of images (not the bar) that tab contains. Can anyone tell me how to do that in Swift?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In your 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

```
(window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

or use appearance delegate.

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: instead of .tintColor = ... try use .barTintColor =

Comment: it only change selected state color

Answer (score 13):

Another good solution:

*Add Runtime Color attribute named "tintColor"*.

It will change image tint color as well as title tint color.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to AppDelegate.swift file. In 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' write:

```swift
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are right here I am sharing to achieve this using story board inspector

select your tab bar go  to inspector and change image tint to your corresponding colour for reference attaching image

[image]